# MySQL Filtering on possible null value

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

i am writing a mysql stored procedure that takes a single datetime parameter. it uses it in a select statement as such..

```
select *
from table
where date >= @datefrom or @datefrom is null
```

when i write t-sql queries this usually does the trick but it doesnt seem to be working with mysql.

i have also tried other variants such as

```
where date >= ifnull(@datefrom, date)
```

and also

```
where ((date >= @datefrom and @datefrom is not null) or (@datefrom is null))
```

but im not getting the results i am expecting..

can someone shed any light on this?

procedure definition as such..

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `prc_xxxxxx`(datefrom datetime)
BEGIN

select * from table
where date >= @datefrom or @datefrom is null

END
```

and then i would call like this..

```
call prc_xxxxxx ('2012-07-04 00:00:00')
```

or

```
call prc_xxxxx (null)
```

Comment: Are you running this query as it appears here? with the @ in the query?

Comment: Try the `NULL`-safe equality operator [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: @ is used for session variables. Has the value of @param been set earlier in the same session?

Comment: Priyank - well its just a parameter - it gets passed in via 'call sp_xxxxx ('')

Comment: eggyal - could you show me how to use it in the above example?

Comment: @Grant If you pass this value as a parameter, then why do you use  `@param` in SELECT statement?

Comment: @param is just a placeholder inn this example. the actual value may be null or it may have a value. i don't want the results trimmed if the param is null. make sense?

Comment: I mean that you should use procedure paramater instead of variable.

Comment: Please show your procedure definition.

Comment: i have added further detail to the original question as well as added the procedure definition. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, the @ symbol is used for [session variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/user-variables.html), not for stored routine parameters—those should go unprefixed. E.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_IN` (IN var1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT var1 + 2 AS result;  
END//
```

This example was taken from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/).

Comment: oh - so we doint use '@' like in T-SQL ??

Comment: Neither MySQL nor Oracle use `@` for stored routine parameters.